# Where do questions about buying a car go?

Tags: discussion

I'd like to ask a question about a Carfax report, but from searching existing questions it looks like the general consensus is that this community is strictly dedicated to vehicle maintenance/repair. Where would this question be on topic?

Answer (score 4):

To be very honest with you, I don't think there is an SE community which would tackle this kind of question. You can always ask your question of this nature in our chat room called [The Pitstop](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/340/the-pitstop). There it is a lot more free form and we can talk about such things.